# Socket.io, Node, Corodva, no logro recibir mensaje desde otro cliente que no sea el emisor

Tags: nodejs, cordova, socket.io

estoy hace horas con esto y no entiendo por qué no me está funcionando, además de que ya he realizado sistemas como chats y jamas tuve problema, esta vez es la primera vez que utilizo Cordova y socket pero no me explico por qué pasa esto.

Resulta que tengo 2 clientes abiertos uno emite mensaje y el otro recibe, esto no me funciona, solo me funciona si el que emite el mensaje también escucha para recibirlo.

Mi código es:

Cliente emisor:

```
socket.emit("callDriver", data);
```

Cliente receptor:

```
socket.on("sendToDriver", function(data){

    console.log(data);

})
```

Servidor:

```
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

io.on('connection', function(socket){

    socket.on('callDriver', function(data){

        console.log(data);

        socket.emit('sendToDriver', data);

    })

})
```

Entonces si el cliente receptor espera al mensaje, el mismo, nunca llega, pero si al mismo cliente emisor le digo que escuche a "sendToDriver" ahí sí llega el mensaje.

Agradezco mucho su ayuda!

Answer (score 0):

bueno, había posteado en stackoverflow inglés, continué googleando y no encontraba solución, cree 2 proyectos nuevos utilizando socket.io, modifiqué cosas, etc, etc hasta que di con la solución.

Es extraño ya que según la documentación oficial de Socket.io desde el lado del servidor tú debes utilizar "socket.emit()" para enviar los datos al cliente, de esta forma solamente me enviaba los datos solo al mismo cliente que los había enviado al servidor únicamente, entonces probé cambiar este "socket.emit" por "io.emit" (variable previamente creada en "var io = require('socket.io')(server)") y de esta forma funcionó!

En conclusión lo que cambié fue:

```js
// Cambié esto:
io.on('connection', function(socket){

    socket.on('callDriver', function(data){

        console.log(data);

        socket.emit('sendToDriver', data);

    })

})

// por esto:
io.on('connection', function(socket){

    socket.on('callDriver', function(data){

        console.log(data);

        io.emit('sendToDriver', data);

    })

})
```

Muchas gracias a la comunidad!